# Need to know for how long a node was up from logs in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have an index in Elasticsearch with following schema:

```
"perf-system-cpu": {
  "mappings": {
    "perf_metric": {
      "properties": {
        "@timestamp": {
          "type": "date"
        },
        "cpu_usage": {
          "type": "float"
        },
        "host_address": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "host_name": {
          "type": "text"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have an agent installed on my app servers which sends CPU usage data from that node to ES every 5 seconds.

Now via this index, I want to know which host is up in `Last n minutes` and for how long it has been running.
According to my understanding, I want to know the difference between the timestamp of first log and last log.

Answer (score 0):

First inclination is to use a [sort](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html) in your query, but if you sort and take the lowest value, its possible that lowest value is from a previous runtime of your application.

What I would suggest doing is adding an `uptime` date value to your mapping.  Cache a startup timestamp value in your applications and then compute `uptime` date when you send data to ES by subtracting current time from start time.  You can then just take the `uptime` from the most recent `@timestamp`.